# nginx 502 with wsgi and flask

Tags: python, nginx, flask, wsgi

I'm trying to launch a python script on my localhost, using flask, wsgi and nginx.

I've been attempting to follow [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-centos-7), but I'm using Raspbian, not CentOS.

In my working directory, I have `wsgi.py` which runs my main python script, `myApp.py`.

```
from myApp import app as application

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

If I run `uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5000 --protocol=http -w wsgi` it works and I can access my script. But I want to use nginx, so I try configuring it.

I have `myApp.ini` in the working directory, which is

```
[uwsgi]
module=wsgi
master=true
processes=5
socket=myApp.sock
chmod-socket=660
vacuum=true
die-on-term=true
```

And then, I went to `/etc/nginx/sites-available`, renamed `default` to `default2` and wrote the following as the new `default`.

```
server {
    listen 5000;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/home/pi/Desktop/WEBSERVER/myApp.sock;
    }
}
```

If I run `sudo service nginx configtest` I get `Testing nginx configuration:.` which I assume is passing. I run `sudo service nginx start` and the service appears to start, but I receive a 502 Bad Gateway error.

Edit: I changed `uwsgi_pass      unix:/home/pi/Desktop/WEBSERVER/myApp.sock;` to `uwsgi_pass      unix:/home/pi/Desktop/WEBSERVER/myApp.ini;`. This change gives me a Permission denied error instead of a No such file error.

Example issues:

No such file

```
2016/12/05 02:20:09 [crit] 1232#0: *1 connect() to unix:///home/pi/Desktop/WEBSERVER/myApp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.15.21, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///home/pi/Desktop/WEBSERVER/myApp.sock:", host: "192.168.15.19:5000"
```

Permission Denied

```
2016/12/05 02:37:09 [notice] 2938#0: signal process started
2016/12/05 02:37:11 [crit] 2942#0: *9 connect() to unix:///home/pi/Desktop/WEBSERVER/myApp.ini failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.15.21, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///home/pi/Desktop/WEBSERVER/myApp.ini:", host: "192.168.15.19:5000"
```

Comment: Check the logs, may be /var/log

Comment: have you deactivated the virtual environment ?

Comment: I see the error: 


`2016/12/05 00:22:57 [crit] 22167#0: *3 connect() to unix:/home/pi/Desktop/WEBSERVER/myApp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.15.21, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/home/pi/Desktop/WEBSERVER/myApp.sock:", host: "192.168.15.19:5000"`

I'm not sure if I should change the .ini file to .sock, or point the conf to myApp.ini.

Comment: I changed the conf to look for `myApp.ini` but now the error logs say permission denied. How can I give nginx the permissions it needs?

Comment: If that's your `wsgi.py` then there is no way it can run: `app` is undefined in that context.

Comment: give permissions, from the guide you mentioned, do chmod 710 /home/user

Comment: @cwallenpoole the app is defined in myApp.py which I didn't post. If I run `uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5000 --protocol=http -w wsgi` then everything works, so I think `wsgi.py` is fine.

Comment: @praveenraj I ran `chmod 710 /home/pi`, with `pi` being my username, and restarted nginx but the permission denied error persists.

Comment: try this chmod -r 710 /home/pi/Desktop/WEBSERVER

Comment: @praveenraj I get `chmod: cannot access ‘710’: No such file or directory`. I tried removing `-r` but this did not help either.

Comment: sorry chmod 710 -R /home/pi/WEBSERVER

Comment: @praveenraj I tried with `chmod 710 -R /home/pi/Desktop/WEBSERVER` and restarted nginx, but the issue was not resolved.

Comment: are you getting permission denied error, again?

Comment: @praveenraj Yes. The full error is `2016/12/05 00:58:25 [crit] 25353#0: *1 connect() to unix:/home/pi/Desktop/WEBSERVER/myApp.ini failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.15.21, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/home/pi/Desktop/WEBSERVER/myApp.ini:", host: "192.168.15.19:5000"`

Comment: did you add nginx user?

Comment: I tried running `sudo usermod -a -G user nginx` as per the guide, but I am told that the nginx user does not exist. In nginx.conf however, the user is listed as `www-data`. I tried running `sudo usermod -a -G user www-data`, and it went through, but it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: try this uwsgi_pass      /home/pi/Desktop/WEBSERVER/myApp.sock; in default file

Comment: I put that line in the default file but `sudo service nginx configtest` tells me `Testing nginx configuration: failed!` and nginx will not start.

Comment: ok try uwsgi_pass unix:///home/pi/Desktop/WEBSERVER/myApp.sock;

Comment: This does not work either. I receive the error: `2016/12/05 01:32:43 [crit] 28719#0: *1 connect() to unix:///home/pi/Desktop/WEBSERVER/myApp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.15.21, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///home/pi/Desktop/WEBSERVER/myApp.sock:", host: "192.168.15.19:5000"`